# Drawing keeps getting stuck to the screen in SDL

Tags: c++, drawing, sdl

In my program what I am drawing gets stuck on to the screen I am drawing on, by this I mean that what I previously drawed onto the screen stays after I call SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(). Here is my code.

```
void tower_manager::render()
    {
        m_tower.draw(camx, camy,m_screen);
        //SDL_BlitSurface(test, NULL, m_screen, NULL);
        SDL_Rect rect = { 32, 32, 32, 32 };
        //draw the tower walls;
        for (int x = 0; x < towerWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < towerHeight * 2; y += 2)
            {
                rect.x = x*blockSize - camx;
                rect.y = y*blockSize - camy;
                SDL_BlitSurface(test, NULL, m_screen, &rect);
            }
        }
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(m_window);
    }
```

Apparently I need at least 10 reputation to post images so I cant post a screen shot but here is an example, you know what happens to the desktop when a windows application freezes and it keeps drawing the same window over and over again and you can draw it around to make art and stuff? That's exactly what it looks like is happening here. Also I have another issue when I call the tower objects method that is originally going to draw the tower using the same code it does not draw or do anything at all(i am passing in a pointer to the screen I am drawing to in its parameter).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to clear the surface regions that you are drawing to.  If you don't, then the screen surface retains the old renderings from previous frames and you are drawing on top of them.  This causes a smearing artifact.

An old optimization (no longer so useful with SDL2 or OpenGL) here is to keep track of dirty rectangles and clear each of them, but the simplest way is to just clear the entire surface each frame before rendering.

So, once per frame do something like this:

```
SDL_FillRect(m_screen, NULL, 0x000000);
```